# Create a JS class: IIFE vs return prototype

Tags: javascript, class, prototype, iife

Let's see two examples in which I'll try to explain what I want to understand.

```
var Car = function(){
  // Init class
  function Car() { };
  // Private func/vars
  var private = { color:'red' };
  // Public func/vars
  Car.prototype = {
    newColor: function(color) { private.color = color },
    getColor: function() { return private.color }
  };

  return Car.prototype; // return with prototype
};

var myCar = new Car();
```

And:

```
var Car = (function(){
  // Init class
  function Car() { };
  // Private func/vars
  var private = { color:'red' };
  // Public func/vars
  Car.prototype = {
    newColor: function(color) { private.color = color },
    getColor: function() { return private.color }
  };

  return Car; // avoid prototype adding parentheses on next line;
})();

var myCar = new Car();
```

Let's see!,
Both class are created as function expression and both work equally.
The only differences between them, are:
The first return the Car function with its prototype property.
The second works returning the Car function, avoiding the prototype property and instead use IIFE.

What's the differences between use `return Car.prototype;` and avoid IIFE and use `return Car;` using IIFE (parentheses at the end of the class declaration).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the theory of how it works in-depth, and what are the technical differences.

Comment: Do you intend to use the `new` operator with both of the `Car` objects returned ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The second code sample is the proper way to achieve what you're looking for.  You create an immediately-executing function, inside of which you create a new function, add to its prototype, and then return it.

The first example is a bit odd, and doesn't quite create a constructor function properly.  The line

```
return Car.prototype; // return with prototype
```

causes your Car function to simply always return the object literal that you had previously assigned to `Car.prototype`.  This overrides the normal behavior of a function invoked with `new`

---

Just one thing to note, this line:

```
Car.prototype = {
   newColor: function(color) { private.color = color },
   getColor: function() { return private.color }
};
```

will cause the `constructor` property of newly create objects to no longer point to your Car function.  There are two easy ways to fix this if this is important to you.

```
Car.prototype = {
   newColor: function(color) { private.color = color },
   getColor: function() { return private.color }
};
Car.prototype.constructor = Car;   // <-------- add this line
```

Or change the above to

```
Car.prototype.newColor = function(color) { private.color = color };
Car.prototype.getColor = function() { return private.color };
```