# javascript calling inner function

Tags: javascript

As a javascript learner, I face an issue:

```
var Wrap=(function(){
        function User(name){
        this.name=name;
        }
        var q=function(){
        return "Thank you coming in "+this.name;
        };

        User.prototype.thankForLoggingIn=q;

        return User;
        })();
```

Please provide the call to have about code return  “Thank you for coming in John”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an instance of `Wrap` first, for example `var user = new Wrap("Adrian");`. Later, using this instance you can just use it as a base to call your `thankForLoggingIn` function as `user.thankForLoggingIn();`.

You are basically simulating a class using a Immediately-invoked Function Expression or simply IIFE. You can read more about them by clicking [here](https://medium.com/@vvkchandra/essential-javascript-mastering-immediately-invoked-function-expressions-67791338ddc6). There is also a nice answer on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226043/create-a-js-class-iife-vs-return-prototype) and an easy article about basic javascript classes implementation [here](https://javascript.info/class). I recommend you to read them.

Below you have a working example for your question. Press the **Run code snippet** button to see how it works.

```js
var Wrap = (function() {
  function User(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  User.prototype.thankForLoggingIn = function() {
    return "Thank you coming in " + this.name;
  };

  return User;
})();

var user1 = new Wrap("Adrian");
var user2 = new Wrap("John");

let greet1 = user1.thankForLoggingIn();
let greet2 = user2.thankForLoggingIn();

console.log(greet1);
console.log(greet2);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
var Wrap = (function () {
    function User(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    User.prototype.thankForLoggingIn = function () {
        return "Thank you coming in " + this.name;
    };
    return User;
})();

var user = new Wrap("foo");
user.thankForLoggingIn();
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22054631)